# Как удалять объекты из UICollectionView?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Подскажите пожалуйста как осуществить удалени объектов по средствам кнопки Эдит или движением пальца по объекту. Просмотрел протоколлы `UICollectionViewDataSource` и `UICollectionViewDelegate`, но ничего похожего на функцию `commitEditingStyle` не нашел. Ткните носом, если не сложно.

Comment: нашёл простой и эффективный выход. добавил батон эдит и через селф эдитинг реагирую на тач